# React native Android - network request failed error with fetch() method

Tags: android, fetch, react-native

Currently, my app is not working, and it prints out an error message "network request failed".

The URL is correct - the URL is woking properly in Chrome, however, it only not working on the android.

I am assuming that it is basically because I am using private certificate for https.

Below is my code, please let me know if you find an answer.

> fetch(url)
>         .then(res => res.json())
>         .then(
>           (result) => {
>             const companyName = result['name'];
>             const companyId = 'ID ' + result['id'];

```
      this.setState({
        isLoaded: true,
        siteData: result,
        companyName: companyName,
        companyID: companyId
      });
    }
  )
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
    this.setState({
      isLoaded: false,
      error
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer is ok, but in my case i had to change the manifest too:

```
<application
...
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
...>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ahh, it works perfectly fine with http - the actual problem was the self-certificate https.

Apparently, the data fetching component in Android blocks the self certificate https due to the security problem.